# How to return boolean out of a stream on a Angular Guard?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am creating an angular guard that tries to use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) Auth's feature, but I don't seem to get it right. Most answers I have found on my research make use of the .map() operator in order to return a boolean result. But I don't know how to apply it to my case (I tried several ways of using map() with no luck).

So this is what I have so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {AuthenticationService} from './services/authentication.service';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe((status) => {
      return (status !== null);
    });
  }
}
```

But it seems to be returning the Observable instead of its resolution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to return boolean. `canActivate` can return `Observable<boolean>` so Angular will wait for result for you and allow activation if returned observable will emit `true`.

Add `map` to transform whatever your service is emmiting into boolean, and return that observable. Something like this:

```
 canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.angularFireAuth.authState
     .pipe(
        map(status => status !== null)
     )
```